# Cannot resolve symbol - Bitmap image compress and upload to Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to select an image, compress it and then upload it to the firebase Storage. I'm trying the following code but getting an error that `Cannot resolve symbol 'data2'`.

This is my activity:

```
private void openFileChooserOne() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK &&
        data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        mImageUri = data.getData();
        Picasso.get().load(mImageUri).into(mImageView);
    }
}

private void uploadFile() {
    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    String userID = user.getUid();
    if (mImageUri != null && mImageMedicalUri != null) {
        StorageReference fileReference = mStorageRef.child(userID).child("image.jpg");
        try {
            Bitmap bmp = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), mImageUri);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 25, baos);
            byte[] data2 = baos.toByteArray();
        } catch (IOException ioEx) {
            ioEx.printStackTrace()
        }
        mUploadTask = fileReference.putBytes(data2) //Getting error here
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener < UploadTask.TaskSnapshot > () {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        //
                    });
            }
    })
}
```

I'm new in Java and trying to understand the problem. Will very much appreciate your help to know what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: data2 is in your try block. its local to that block. move upload code inside try block

Comment: Thank you very much. It works perfectly now.  @Raghunandan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using the following line of code:

```
mUploadTask = fileReference.putBytes(data2)
```

Your `data2` variable is outside the scope where it was declared. To solve this, you should either move this line inside the try-catch block or make the `data2` variable as a global variable.

Comment: Is there everything alright, can I help you with other informations?

Comment: Thank you very much. It's working perfectly. Cheers.